# How to disallow a period in a JSON-schema pattern

Tags: regex, jsonschema

I would like to add a period to the following banned character set in a JSON schema pattern:

```
"pattern": "[^\"{}:, \t]+"
```

My first thought was to try:

```
"pattern": "[^\.\"{}:, \t]+"
```

but this produces a parse error of the schema.

My next thought was to try:

```
"pattern": "[^\\.\"{}:, \t]+"
```

but this does not have the desired property when I try to validate my YAML file.

I am using ajv as my JSON schema validation tool, and I am validating a YAML file.

Comment: a regex when using a character class  doesn't require to escape the dot. For the sake of records

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As axiac and Diego D note, the period does not need to be escaped in the character class.  However, in addition to that problem the pattern was not matching anything because it lacked the prefix `^` and suffix `$`.  The final pattern is:

```
"pattern": "^[^\"{}:., \t]+$"
```

Answer (score 0):

`.` is **not** a special character in character classes. Only `^`, `-` and `]` are special characters and have to be escaped in character classes.
`^` and `-` can even be used without escaping in a character class if they are not placed in positions where they have special meaning.

Your successful attempt added both `.` and `\` in the character class.

Just add `.` somewhere in the character class (not before `^`) and that's all:

```json
"pattern": "[^\"{}:., \t]+"
```